# Couchbase lite without phonegap plugin

Tags: angular, ionic2, couchbase-lite

I wanted to build a hybrid mobile application using Ionic,angular4, couchbase. Later to make application run offline, I wanted to use couchbase lite. I have Found a reference of to-do list app in github which uses phonegap plugin.Is that really required or as I am using ionic which uses cordova gives any solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PhoneGap plugin with Ionic as a Cordova plugin also.